# What is the alternative to AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Is there a Scheduler api in RxJava synonymous to AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() in RxAndroid. 
So If I schedule a task on a new thread and I want to observe it on Java Main Thread, how would I do that?

*edit*
Below is an example RxSubscription, with system.in commented, the Main thread is killed while the Observable.interval runs on a separate thread. In Android, I can say observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.MainThread) and any operation thereafter would run on the main thread. I am looking for a similar scheduler in Java as AndroidSchedulers is part of RxAndroid.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import rx.Observable;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    Observable<Long> values = Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    values.subscribe(
            v -> System.out.println("Received: " + v),
            e -> System.out.println("Error: " + e),
            () -> System.out.println("Completed")
    );
    //System.in.read();
}
}
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know *why* you need that. Since there is only one main thread, there's not much options.

Comment: Why do you need to observe something on a specific thread? in Android the main thread has special significance, what's your requirement?

Comment: @Ascorbin edited question to elaborate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting back to the "main" Java thread is currently not possible as there is no blocking Scheduler for RxJava 1.x.

In case you can upgrade to RxJava 2.x, I have a special Scheduler that can be "pinned" to the current thread:

```
compile "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.15.1"
```

> **BlockingScheduler**
>
> This type of scheduler runs its execution loop on the "current thread", more specifically, the thread which invoked its execute() method. The method blocks until the shutdown() is invoked. This type of scheduler allows returning to the "main" thread from other threads.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockingScheduler scheduler = new BlockingScheduler();

    scheduler.execute(() -> {
        Flowable.range(1, 10)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> scheduler.shutdown())
            .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v + " on " + Thread.currentThread()));
    });

    System.out.println("BlockingScheduler finished");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, RxJava has schedulers.  To send a message to any thread, you need to have a message loop of some sort waiting for messages from the other threads.  In Android this is your Looper.  In Java, you'd need to do that yourself.  Your Scheduler would then send a message to that thread and do the work in that message response.  The mechanism for that depends on how you implement your message queue, but should be fairly trivial.